# Keyboard characters not corresponding to the right key with windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, keyboard

I have a Genius keyboard that plugs into a usb, when I use it on my windows 10 computer the @ character types a ", and # types a £ and forward slash types a # and I don't even know where the forward slash character is?
I plugged it into my sisters computer and the keyboard works fine (she is still using windows 7) how do I fix windows 10?

Comment: Change the keyboard layout.

Comment: Edit your question and include a screenshot of the installed keyboard layouts you have installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is most likely something messed up with the keyboard layout. To change that you have to go to the settings and then to **Time & Language**. There you go to **Region & Language**. You can add now your prefered keyboard layout and set it as default.